Tomcat problems after server IP change
Our server hosting company changed the internal ip of our Debian server and they made the proper changes in /etc/host file.
After this change I am not able to run a tomcat war file that I set up years ago. The .war app is called ROOT.war and have been working fine for years.
Now when I try to reach the app through port 8080 (http://my-server.com:8080) I get the message "Http status 404" "The requested resource is not available.".
Nothing has changed in the /user/local/apache-tomcatNNNNN folder.
I have tried to alter the values from "localhost" to the IP address in conf/server.xml but get the same error message.
Have also tried deleting the extracted .WAR directory and the contents of the tomcat work directory but to no avail.
